# I is there an R function for transforming map projection to the Waterman Butterfly?

Tags: r, d3.js, maps, projection, map-projections

I need to use R to plot a world map in the [Waterman Butterfly projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterman_butterfly_projection). None of the mapping packages I am familiar with (maps, ggmap, mapproj, leaflet) allow this transformation.

Is anyone familiar with an approach or function out there that I could use? Google has not helped.

I did find a [javascript D3 plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/) that allows the transformation, but I do not know javascript and the reading I've done about binding D3/javascript to R is intimidating. If you know of a streamlined way to use this D3 function within R I would be very grateful to hear it.

[image: Waterman butterfly example]

A simple example of what I am starting with, including a transformation to a randomly selected projection from mapproj library:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mapproj)
ggplot(data = map_data('world'), aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group))+
geom_polygon(fill="black")+
coord_map(projection="guyou")+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
panel.grid.major = element_line(color="grey"),
axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.title = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R, I edited the question to remove the reference to a request for a package and added a minimum working example.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `HTMLWidgets` plugin for R, it allows for easier integration between JS and R.

Here's a link to their [docs](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html).

You'll need to import D3 similar to their example with Sigma.

However, since you're just looking for D3 there's also [R2D3](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/), which is pretty streamlined.

Comment: This is a great find but please provide a working example or redirect the link-based answer to a comment (that's the official way of doing it anyway). Great find!

Comment: This is a great find, and I will explore further...although on first pass, it will take some time for me to figure out how to make this work. Your link did lead me to the [r2d3maps](https://github.com/dreamRs/r2d3maps) package, which is a very easy way to make simple D3 maps from sf objects... and feels like a foot in the door, for someone who knows javascript. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to incorporate or reference the plugin to be able to use the extended projections from d3-geo-projection.